# how to unserialize postgresql array as a ruby Set instead of an Array in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, postgresql-9.3

I am trying to unserialize pg Array to set instead of Array and reserialize them to pg array on save. This would make my data not accept duplicate.

Just pointing me to the right direction would be very usefull.

thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [serialize method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html#method-i-serialize) - you can stipulate which class you want it serialized to/from.